# Renaming [stellarjs] tag to include the dot

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

According to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197731/214186), the best way to ask for tag renaming is opening a question, rather than contacting a Moderator♦ privately... so here I am.

Not a big deal, but reading [stellarjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stellarjs) without the dot is becoming my pet peeve;

since the library is called **STELLAR.JS**, the [URI](http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/) ends with `/stellar.js/` and similar tags on StackOverflow have all the dot separating the extension ([backbone.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/backbone.js), [node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node.js), [parallax.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parallax.js), and so on), so it's not some kind of SO naming convention... let's change it :)

Note: an exception is made for [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) that, in fact, has no dot in its name.

Comment: Please retag this question if it's tagged badly. I'm not familiar with MSO tags

Comment: thanks @StevenV, didn't know tag: syntax :P

Comment: The only reason you might not want to do this is that [dots in tag names are not ignored like other punctuation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157765/135887), resulting in relatively frequent creation of dotted/undotted tags for which there is already an undotted/dotted version.  The current tag name might be wrong, but it's also still discoverable.  Thankfully there are only like 25 questions, so this is a job easily doable by a single human being.

Comment: @Charles Can't you solve that problem by creating a non-dotted synonym?

Comment: @CodyGray, while synonyms could help solve the problem, the synonym system is procedurally broken due to voting requirements.

Comment: Thanks for commenting @Charles; BTW if without dot is better, then should we leave this tag as-is... and rename all the others ? :|

Comment: Oh, [I couldn't agree more](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103211/can-we-allow-7-5k-users-to-suggest-tag-synonyms-without-a-score-of-5-in-the-tag).

Comment: Oh, done. GREAT :)